# How to hide login button after clicking button

Tags: angularjs

Kindly share me details about how to solve.I have two buttons login and signup on clicking login button user name and password appears and submit button,but i want login and signup button to hidden.

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myController',function($scope,myService){
    $scope.resta={};
    $scope.save=true;
    $scope.redirect=function(){
    
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" >
  <div class="container" class="form-group"  ng-show="login">
    <label>Username:</label><input ng-model="username" class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Enter your username">
    <label>Password:</label><input type="password" ng-model="password" 
    class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="redirect()" >Logging in</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container" class="form-group" ng-show="signup">
    <label>Name:</label><input ng-model="resta.name" class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Enter your name">
    <label>Mobile:</label><input ng-model="resta.mobile" class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Enter your number">
    <label>EmailId:</label><input ng-model="resta.email" class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Enter your email">
    <label>Password:</label><input ng-model="resta.password" class="form-
    control" 
    placeholder="Enter your password">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()"  >Registering</button>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="login=true" >Login</button>
  <button ng-click="signup=true">SignUp</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-hide or ng-show to modify the visibility of elements based on variables in scope.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController',['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.login = false;
  $scope.signup = false;
  $scope.resta = {};
  $scope.save = true;
  $scope.redirect = function() {}
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="container" class="form-group" ng-show="login">
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input ng-model="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your username">
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" ng-model="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="redirect()">Logging in</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container" class="form-group" ng-show="signup">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input ng-model="resta.name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name">
    <label>Mobile:</label>
    <input ng-model="resta.mobile" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your number">
    <label>EmailId:</label>
    <input ng-model="resta.email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email">
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input
      ng-model="resta.password"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Enter your password"
    >
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()">Registering</button>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="login=true" ng-hide="login">Login</button>
  <button ng-click="signup=true" ng-hide="signup">SignUp</button>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to inject the scope service into your controller for it to work properly. Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 0):

Give your buttons IDs and use javascript or jQuery to hide them.

Pure Javascript

```
<button id="loginButton" ng-click="login=true">Login</button>
<script>
    document.getElementByID("loginButton").style.display = "none";
</script>
```

jQuery

```
<button id="loginButton" ng-click="login=true">Login</button>
<script>
    $("#loginButton").hide();
</script>
```

Comment: Using JQuery to modify DOM state in Angular is heavily discouraged. You almost never need JQuery when you have Angular, and having both will increase load times.